# Example of von Neumann regular ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

Every field is von Neumann regular ring.

I'm looking for an example of von Neumann regular ring 
but not field.

Comment: Check the example here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_regular_ring

Comment: [LMDTFY](http://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/search/results/?H=14&L=2).

Answer (score 0):

- A product of fields.
- A matrix ring over a field $K$$\mathcal M_n(K)$.
- A Boolean ring.